# How to find the absolute value of a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

In my linear algebra course I keep seeing something like this:

a = {1, 3, 5}

Then in formulas I see this:

|a|

What does this mean, what is the absolute value of a vector? Wouldn't just be {1,3,5}?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Keep in mind that absolute value is *distance from zero*. So you can use the distance formula to find the absolute value:

$$
\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}
$$

Comment: It wouldn't happen to be coincidence that this also equals the sqrt of a dot producted with itself would it? Is there any significance there

Comment: Yep, it is exactly the same thing. For a dot product, you multiply corresponding elements: here, we multiply the x, y, and z values.

Comment: Shouldn't that result in the authors question's answer being 5 since the sum of those squares leads to 25 and thus the square root of 25 being 5 and thus the answer too.  Also, is this generally accepted as the way to calculate the value of a given vector when given e.g. |v|?

Comment: @user784446 - The sum of squares is $35$, not $25$.

Answer (score 11):

Absolute value of a vector means taking second norm of the vector i.e. $\|x\|$. That means the same thing as $\sqrt{x_1^2 +x_2^2+...+x_n^2}$. I don't understand why some top researchers in computer science abuse the notation where $|x|$ is widely used for absolute value of scalars in math.

I have also seen papers using $|x|$ to mean absolute value of each component of the vector $x$. In summary, meaning will depends upon the context and author.

Comment: This is not helpful at all......

Comment: @JohnMa, can you explain me how?  or if you know what does $|x|$ exactly mean, where x is a vector?

Comment: If the OP knows what is a norm, probably (s)he won't ask this question. Moreover, you are just changing the notation from $|x|$ to $\|x\|$. How is that helpful? Will the OP get the definition after seeing your answer?

Comment: @JohnMa. Thanks. I should have taken Ogen knowledge level into account.